# How to split strings in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have implementing the android application for split the file path and get the actual file name in text-view. When I run the application it displays all the String name from file path. I want only one file name (introduction.ppt). How can I get this file name in text-view?

Here is my code:

```
String path = "/mnt/sdcard/coverted/introduction.ppt";    
String[] strAfterSpilt = path.split("/");

for(int j = 0; j < strAfterSpilt.length; j++) {
    if(strAfterSpilt[j].length() > 0) {
        String strFinalSplit = strAfterSpilt[j];
        System.out.println("strFinalSplit :-> " + strFinalSplit);
        function_arg1.setText(strFinalSplit);
    } else { break; } 
}
```

And also I have to try this way of split the file path;

```
String[] strAfterSpilt = path.split("/");

for (String str : strAfterSpilt) {
    System.out.println("str" + str.lastIndexOf(strAfterSpilt[i]));
}
```

Comment: you should check on google once before asking question. it's nothing like android provide any different mechanism for splitting String than java.

Comment: @PankajKumar Asking for upvotes is not good.  Upvotes are for answers which are better than average, provide new information, are innovative, cover topics which are not well known etc.  Such a simple question should not deserve upvotes.

Comment: @PankajKumar No one is obliged to explain their downvotes. I suggest you chill out and don't worry about it.

Comment: @sgroves Although that was very old comment... thank you for your valuable solution :). It reminded me to remove that comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String path = "/mnt/sdcard/coverted/introduction.ppt";
String fileName = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

will do your job.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] tokens = path.split("/");
String fileName = tokens[tokens.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try following code.. specifying the start and end position of required string.

```
String path = "/mnt/sdcard/coverted/introduction.ppt";
String fileName = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/"), path.length);
```

Comment: Not yet, but you just go through the http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=31 , you will get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try out following codes

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
String path = "/mnt/sdcard/coverted/introduction.ppt";
String fileName;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            // To get the File name
    fileName = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
    TextView remotefilePath =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtFileName);
    remotefilePath.setText(fileName);
    }
}
```